# Schottky TTL current calculator

Tags: transistors, ttl, schottky, nand

[image]

I have a problem from university where I have to calculate the I ccl. I am a little bit confused because I don't know how to do it.

The problem says as well that Schottky TTL state is 0 logic (I think that means 0 logic in the output). That being said, I ccl should be 0? But how do you calculate it?

Comment: Welcome! Have you tried to simulate it (numerical solution)? Or do you need to calculate an expression for it?

Comment: Hey, I have to calculate the value, but without a simulation. Bascially the expression and then change the values

Comment: EE&O, there are 2 cases ... when input is 0 V, or input = 5 V. In all cases, do a DC analysis. NB: there is '3' parts in the behavior.

Comment: @Antonio51 ... what does "EE&O" mean?

Comment: Show us all of your work so far. This is not a homework solution service.

Comment: I understand your point. But I think I am extremly dumb now:)) I usually know how to calculate the curent/tension of a transistor, but here it's like completly different. I myself hate to give exact solution or to request it.

Comment: Everything I know is that If the scheme is 0 logic, that means 0 in the output, q2 and qp2 should be blocked, q1 reverse active and the rest of transistors should be saturated.

Comment: @jonathanjo EE&O mean "Excepted Error and Omissions". Alas, we are not perfect.

Comment: @FlorinSebastian To have some idea of the answer, make a simulated DC analysis, you will have a better "view" of how you should "calculate" what you are searching ...

Answer (score 2):

I<sub>CC</sub>, the supply current, is defined as the current that flows into V<sub>CC</sub> *and* out of GND. So you can ignore any currents that flow into or out of the input/output pins.

This is the circuit of an inverter (the SN74S04). To get a low output, the input must be pulled high, to V<sub>CC</sub>.

Just do a DC analysis. You will find that the lower output transistor (Q<sub>O</sub>) is active, and that the upper one (Q<sub>P2</sub>) is inactive. (If not, you have made an error.) One wrinkle is that the input is a TTL input, i.e., when the input is high, the base-collector junction of Q<sub>1</sub> is used as a diode.

Comment: And how I am supossed to find the expression? I never did that for thoose type of circuits

Comment: All transistors are used as switches, so β does not matter, and all the current goes into a transistor's base or is completely shunted away. You have to make an assumption about V_CE of the Schottky transistors.

Comment: maybe it sounds stupid, could you give me the solution?

Comment: @FlorinSebastian That's not what we do here. If you want help you must put in a substantial effort yourself.

Comment: We are an uncaring internet.  Show some effort and we will help, but what do you learn if we do the hard work for you.

Answer (score 1):

These problems usually require making assumptions about what state each transistor is: saturated, linear region, or off. Then the circuit is analyzed under such assumptions. At the end, the node currents and voltages are checked against the assumptions. For example, if some transistor you’ve assumed in linear region has 0.2Vce, then it’s likely saturated, and you have to redo the problem.

Once the transistor state is assumed, you replace the transistors with their simplified equivalent collector-emitter models: open circuit, base current-controlled current source, or a saturation voltage source. In all three cases, there is a base-emitter diode present.

These simplified - linearized transistor models can be then analyzed using basic circuit analysis techniques. The goal is to “get rid of” transistors for analysis and use simple equivalent models. The circuit you’ll actually analyze will have linearized diodes, resistors, voltage and current sources.  not transistors.

Usually some intuition helps with figuring out what state are the transistors in. You can also run the circuit in a simulator or even on the breadboard. The Schottky transistors can be breadboarded using regular BJTs with an external B-C Schottky diode.

Answer (score 0):

As proposed, do a dynamic DC Analysis and you should be given this resulting picture ...
This circuit is one of the proposed circuits for the 74LS04 inverter.
This will help you to do the "work of calculating" the current you are searching.

Begin at left and see with caution all the voltages and currents.
Try understanding and go to the right where the "current" you need is.

[image]

Comment: Much appreciated man, it really helps